# Pandas: Change day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `datetime` series, and need to change the day to `1` for each entry. I have thought of numerous simple solutions, but none of them works for me. For now, the only thing that actually works is

- set the series as the index
- Query month and year from the index
- Reconstruct a new time series using year, month and 1

It can't really be that complicated, can it? There is month start, but is unfortunately an `offset`, that's of no use here. There seems to be no `set()` function for the method, and even less functionality while the series is a column, and not (part of) the index itself.

The only related question was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233107/pandas-convert-datetime-to-end-of-month), but the trick used there is not applicable here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The other two answers work, but neither is very elegant nor in the spirit of the `pandas` library. Instead, consider this, which is also ever so slightly faster in my tests then Kyle Barron's vectorized answer. It's a one liner that does not require defining any outside functions, is vectorized, and stays within the `pandas` ecosystem:

```py
import pandas as pd
dtseries.dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()
```

This method has the added benefit of supporting many other frequencies to floor to, such as weekly (`'W'`) or business days (`'B'`) that would be trickier to implement with the vectorized approach above.

You can find the abbreviations for various other frequencies [in the relevant doc page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

This of course assumes that `dtseries` is a datetime series, if not you can easily convert it with `pd.to_datetime(my_series)`.

This solution also allows for great flexibility in using various offsets. For example, to use the tenth day of the month:

```py
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
dtseries.dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp() + DateOffset(days=10)
```

I recommend you check the [doc for pandas offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/offset_frequency.html). The offsets pandas provides support a lot of rather complex offsets, such as business days, holidays, business hours, etc... Those would be extremely cumbersome to implement by hand as proposed by the answers of @KyleBarron and @JonClements. Consider this example for instance, to get dates offset 5 business days from the start of the month:

```py
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BusinessDay
dtseries.dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp() + BusinessDay(n=5)
```

Comment: Note that this applies only to the special case where you want to floor to a predefined frequency. If you want to set all dates to, say, day 10, then I don't see a way to use this.

Comment: @KyleBarron No, that would still work. You would only have to add a [date offset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html). See my edit :)

Comment: @KyleBarron In fact, I would argue that my solution is on the contrary much more flexible in dealing with complex offsets. How would yours deal with the business day case for example?

Comment: Those are good points, and the edit explains it well. From a simple test your answer looks to be 5% faster than mine. I don't work with dates in pandas anymore, but I think yours is most generalized.

Comment: I only had to call the offset function like this and it worked perfectly as I previously had imported pandas as pd: `pd.DateOffset(days=10)`

Answer (score 48):

You can use `.apply` and `datetime.replace`, eg:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

ps = pd.Series([datetime(2014, 1, 7), datetime(2014, 3, 13), datetime(2014, 6, 12)])
new = ps.apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(day=1))
```

Gives:

```
0   2014-01-01
1   2014-03-01
2   2014-06-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: For a vectorized solution that stays within the pandas ecosystem, consider my answer below.

Comment: Not wrong but rather slow on large frames

Answer (score 37):

The other answer works, but any time you use `apply`, you slow your code down *a lot*. I was able to get an 8.5x speedup by writing a quick vectorized Datetime replace for a series.

```py
def vec_dt_replace(series, year=None, month=None, day=None):
    return pd.to_datetime(
        {'year': series.dt.year if year is None else year,
         'month': series.dt.month if month is None else month,
         'day': series.dt.day if day is None else day})
```

Apply:

```
%timeit dtseries.apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(day=1))
# 4.17 s ± 38.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Vectorized:

```
%timeit vec_dt_replace(dtseries, day=1)
# 491 ms ± 6.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Note that you could face errors by trying to change dates to ones that don't exist, like trying to change 2012-02-29 to 2013-02-29. Use the `errors` argument of [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to ignore or coerce them.

Data generation: Generate series with 1 million random dates:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate random dates. Modified from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668285
def pp(start, end, n):
    start_u = start.value // 10 ** 9
    end_u = end.value // 10 ** 9

    return pd.Series(
        (10 ** 9 * np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n)).view('M8[ns]'))

start = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
dtseries = pp(start, end, 1000000)
# Remove time component
dtseries = dtseries.dt.normalize()
```