# How to manipulate pandas datetime objects to get the last date of previous month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe and want to turn all the dates into the last date of the previous month. For example "2020-02-04" should turn into "2020-01-31", "2020-03-03" should turn into "2020-02-28" and so on. My df looks like this (in the month column I already have the right month for my wanted date) :

```
In[76]: dfall[["date", "month"]]
Out[76]: 
       date    month
0 2020-02-04      1
1 2020-03-03      2
2 2020-04-02      3
3 2020-05-05      4
4 2020-06-03      5
5 2020-07-02      6
```

Now I tried this:

```
import calendar
import datetime
today = datetime.now()
dfall.date = str(today.year) + "-" + str(dfall.month) + "-" + str(calendar.monthrange(today.year,dfall.month)[1])
```

The idea was to build the new date by adding the strings together. But this code raises an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I know the error is coming from this part: `str(calendar.monthrange(today.year,dfall.month)[1])` (without this part the codes runs without error but the result is not what I want). It's probably because python doesnt know which month to take from `dfall.month`. Does anybody know how I could handle that problem?

Comment: It'll be good if you consider accepting or upvoting an answer to reward those who helped you, or if there is something wrong you could leave a comment too ;) @thyhmoo

Comment: yes you're right, I upvoted every answer but didn't accept one yet. I did it know:)

Comment: No worries! Glad you found your answer :) @thyhmoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `'date'` column is of type string (use `.astype(str)` or `strftime` otherwise), you can cast the year-month part to `datetime` and subtract a `timedelta` of one day:

```
dfall['lastdaylastmonth'] = pd.to_datetime(dfall['date'].str[:-3]) - pd.Timedelta(days=1)

# dfall['lastdaylastmonth']
# 0   2020-01-31
# 1   2020-02-29
# 2   2020-03-31
# 3   2020-04-30
# 4   2020-05-31
# 5   2020-06-30
# Name: lastdaylastmonth, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could try this instead:

```
dfall.date=dfall.date.apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1)- pd.Timedelta(days=1))
```

If the `dfall.date` is type string, try this instead:

```
dfall.date=pd.to_datetime(dfall.date).apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1)- pd.Timedelta(days=1))
```

---

You could try this another vectorized alternative, made by [Kyle Barron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51529633/13676202), to avoid the usage of `df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1))` and [speeds up to **8.5x** the performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51529633/13676202):

```
def vec_dt_replace(series, year=None, month=None, day=None):
    return pd.to_datetime(
        {'year': series.dt.year if year is None else year,
         'month': series.dt.month if month is None else month,
         'day': series.dt.day if day is None else day})
#dfall.date=pd.to_datetime(dfall.date) #(if dfall.date is type string)
dfall.date=vec_dt_replace(dfall.date,day=1)- pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

---

If you want to keep your original solution, then:

- Change `str(dfall.month)` to `dfall.month.astype(str)`
- Change `str(calendar.monthrange(today.year,dfall.month)[1])` to `dfall.month.apply(lambda x:calendar.monthrange(today.year,x)[1]).astype(str)`
- Once you have the string you should cast it to datetime: `pd.to_datetime(dfall.date)`

```
import calendar
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
dfall.date = str(today.year) + "-" + dfall.month.astype(str) + "-" + dfall.month.apply(lambda x:calendar.monthrange(today.year,x)[1]).astype(str)
dfall.date = pd.to_datetime(dfall.date)
print(dfall)
```

---

Output of all solutions:

```
dfall[["date", "month"]]

        date  month
0 2020-01-31      1
1 2020-02-29      2
2 2020-03-31      3
3 2020-04-30      4
4 2020-05-31      5
5 2020-06-30      6
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timeldelta

def convert_date(date_str):
    date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return (date - timedelta(days=date.day)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

dfall.date.apply(convert_date)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, but unfortunately the format looks like "2020-1-31" and pandas is not able to turn that into a datetime object. It needs to be "2020-01-31" for that. Anyway I found a solution from the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({"date":['2020-02-04','2020-03-03','2020-04-02','2020-05-05','2020-06-03','2020-07-02'],
                  "month": [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

# Conert to data
def change_time_format(series):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(series,"%Y-%m-%d")

df.date = df.date.apply(change_time_format)

dates = list(df.date)
previous_m_last_date = []
for d in dates:
    days = d.day
    u_date = d - timedelta(days)
    previous_m_last_date.append(u_date)

df["updated_date"] = previous_m_last_date
df
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
import datetime

for index, d in df.iterrows():
    temp = d["date"]
    dtObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(temp, "%Y-%m-%d")
    newDt = dtObj - datetime.timedelta(days=dtObj.day)
    df["date"][index] = datetime.datetime.strftime(newDt, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 1):

from datetime import datetime

## List of Dates

dates = [datetime(2020, 2, 4), datetime(2020, 3, 3),
datetime(2020, 4, 2), datetime(2020, 5, 5),
datetime(2020, 6, 3), datetime(2020, 7, 2)]

## Values for Month column

month = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

## Create Series with dates as index

ts = pd.Series(month, index=dates)

## Shift dates back one month and store in date_col

date_col = ts.shift(-1, freq='M').index

## Use modified dates as column in DataFrame

pd.DataFrame({'Dates': date_col, 'Month': month})