# how to get the last day of the month from a given date

Tags: python, date

I have a column of dates in my dataframe and I'd like to get the last day of the month from the dates
example, if the date is '2017-01-25' I want to get '2017-01-31'
I suppose I can get the month and year number from the dates and use monthrange to figure out the last day of the month but I'm looking for a one line code

Comment: Since you mention dataframes, I'm assuming you're using pandas? 
 Because if so, this question is basically a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233107/pandas-convert-datetime-to-end-of-month): you can do `df['column_with_dates'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have a date `d` then the simplest way is to use the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module to find the number of days in the month:

```
datetime.date(d.year, d.month, calendar.monthrange(d.year, d.month)[-1])
```

Alternatively, using only `datetime`, we just find the first day of the next month and then remove a day:

```
datetime.date(d.year + d.month // 12, 
              d.month % 12 + 1, 1) - datetime.timedelta(1)
```

You might find the logic clearer if expressed as:

```
datetime.date(d.year + (d.month == 12), 
              (d.month + 1 if d.month < 12 else 1), 1) - datetime.timedelta(1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple Pandas has a Function:

```py
pd.Period('10-DEC-20',freq='M').end_time.date()
```

Use `freq='M'` to modify your requirements

`end_time` for month end
`start_time` for start day

Give output as :

[Output Image - Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yssp2.png)

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to do this is to use:-

```
pandas.offset.MonthEnd(n=1)
```

So the code goes like this:-

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Timestamp("2014-01-02") + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=1)
```

Output:-

```
Timestamp('2014-01-31 00:00:00')
```

Here, I am also attaching the [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offset-semantics) for reference of other useful things.

Hope, this answer your question.

Comment: `n=1` can be left out, ie `pd.offsets.MonthEnd()`

Answer (score 0):

Finding the last date of a month with

```
year, month = 2017, 2
pd.date_range('{}-{}'.format(year, month), periods=1, freq='M')
```

Answer (score -1):

I get the first of the month and minus  one day to get the last day of the month.

```
ccyymmdd = str((pd.Period(datetime.today().replace(day=1), 'D') - 1).strftime("%C%y-%m-%d"))
```