# How to get the last date of every date in a date column in Python so that the for loop can be avoided?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[how to get the last day of the month from a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106552/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-a-given-date/47071286)

Referring to the above repo, I have a similar question I have a data of number of rows 2107260 and number of columns 8, a snapshot of the data:
[image]

Now the issue is that I am trying to have the Date column look like this:

[image]

Now what I have done is:

```
df2_1=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Chirantan.Gupta\\Desktop\\Poland_Project\\V1_Data_SFS_2017_21.csv",low_memory=False)


import calendar

from datetime import timedelta

from datetime import date

df2_1['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df2_1['Date'], format='%Y-%d-%m')

df2_1['Date']= df2_1['Date'].dt.date

for i in range(df2_1.shape[0]):

    df2_1.iloc[i,6]=date(df2_1.iloc[i,6].year + (df2_1.iloc[i,6].month == 12), 
              (df2_1.iloc[i,6].month + 1 if df2_1.iloc[i,6].month < 12 else 1), 1) - timedelta(1)
```

The issue is this data being huge takes humongous time to run and as a consequence it is infeasible, in my opinion. My question is: Is there any way I can have this thing done without having the for loop as I have used, I am running out of ideas here, if anyone can help please.

Comment: How long does it take? Do you even need to change the date to the last day of the month? Couldn't the consumer of this CSV simply know what the date column represents (which is the first day of the month rather than the last day of the month).

Comment: @jarmod A couple of hours, I started it at 8:40 PM, it is 10:50 still running..

Comment: The standard approach to this problem is `df2_1['Date'] = df2_1['Date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)` or `df2_1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2_1['Date']) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)` if the column is not already of type datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repurposing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/how-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-month).

Use the given function:

```
import datetime

def last_day_of_month(any_day):
    # this will never fail
    # get close to the end of the month for any day, and add 4 days 'over'
    next_month = any_day.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)
    # subtract the number of remaining 'overage' days to get last day of current month, or said programattically said, the previous day of the first of next month
    return next_month - datetime.timedelta(days=next_month.day)
```

Then after converting the 'Date' column to datetimes, apply last_day_of_month to all items in the Date column like so:

```
df2_1['Date']= df2_1['Date'].apply(last_day_of_month)
```

Comment: When you use the apply function, it will run last_day_of_month on each item in the column. Let me know if you have tried running this code.

Comment: No It works. Thankyou so much @belfner

Comment: Np. Is it faster?

Comment: Absolutely in a blink of an eye..