# pandas convert date (quarters) to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that has a column (Title) that needs to be parsed as a datetime object so I can turn this into a time series.

```
    Title   Gross Domestic Product: Quarter on Quarter growth: CVM SA %
224 2009 Q3 0.1
225 2009 Q4 0.4
226 2010 Q1 0.5
```

can anyone point out what would be the best approach to this?

my desired output would be

```
    Title   Gross Domestic Product: Quarter on Quarter growth: CVM SA %
224 2009-09 0.1
225 2009-12 0.4
226 2010-03 0.5
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there is no space between the Year and the Quarter, pandas can parse it so you need to replace the space character:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Title'].str.replace(' ', '')) + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)
Out: 
0   2009-09-30
1   2009-12-31
2   2010-03-31
Name: Title, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

By default it gives you the start date of the quarter so I added an offset as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233107/pandas-convert-datetime-to-end-of-month).