# How to Convert a specialty date string to a datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following pandas data frame loaded from a csv file, with the first column (yearly quarter) as displayed.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 44 entries, 0 to 43
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Quarter     44 non-null object
Earnings    44 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 784.0+ bytes
None

 Quarter  Earnings
 0  2007Q1     -0.36
 1  2007Q2     -0.38
 2  2007Q3      0.07
 3  2007Q4      1.85
 4  2008Q1     -0.34
```

I would like the first column transformed into this (below). Is there some type of python or pandas datetime function to do this

```
In [1]: print(HRB)
            Earnings
Quarter             
2007-01-01     -0.36
2007-04-01     -0.38
2007-07-01      0.07
2007-10-01      1.85
2008-01-01     -0.34
2008-04-01     -0.42
2008-07-01      0.02
```

Here is the raw csv data

```
Quarter,Earnings
2007Q1,-0.36
2007Q2,-0.38
2007Q3,0.07
2007Q4,1.85
2008Q1,-0.34
2008Q2,-0.42
2008Q3,0.02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the yearly quarter is contained in the column named `quarter` in the dataframe `data`, below code converts them to datetime objects.

`print(data)`

```
    quarter
0   2007Q1
1   2007Q2
2   2007Q3
3   2007Q4
4   2008Q1
```

`pd.to_datetime(data['quarter'])`

```
0   2007-01-01
1   2007-04-01
2   2007-07-01
3   2007-10-01
4   2008-01-01
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088085/pandas-convert-date-quarters-to-datetime-object) should give you more details.

Comment: When I tried your answer it throws this error, I edited the question to give more detail on the data frame and raw data.AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 1 HRB.to_datetime(data['quarter'])

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Comment: O.K. I figured out how to use the pd.to_datetime() command you answered with, and (yes) it worked great. Thank you.

Comment: Glad, I could help.