# Converting a Year-quarter string to date object in R

Tags: r, date

I have below string

```
dat = '2008Q1'
```

I want to convert this to a `date` object, so I tried below,

```
as.Date(dat, format = '%Y%Q')
```

This gives

```
NA
```

In `python`, there is a direct method as stated in [How to Convert a specialty date string to a datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738197/how-to-convert-a-specialty-date-string-to-a-datetime-object)

Is there any function available in `R` to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest with {lubridate}

```
library(lubridate)

yq(dat)
#[1] "2008-01-01"
```

Alternative with {zoo}

```
library(zoo)

as.Date(as.yearqtr(dat, format = "%YQ%q"))

#[1] "2008-01-01"
```

Comment: Also consider using the output from `as.yearqtr` without converting it to a date since you are trying to represent years and quarters which is what yearqtr objects do and using dates to do that seems more like a workaround.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Good point. When I check `class(as.yearqtr)` returns "yearqtr" while `class(as.Date(as.yearqtr))` returns "Date" . OP does ask for a "`date` object".

Comment: This wasn't intended to be so much a comment on the answer but a comment on the question.  The poster may not have realized that a year/quarter object is available.

Comment: Ah OK; in any case, it's all helpful in getting a better understanding of R.